# adding date range to custom attribute magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Is there any way to add a date range to a custom attribute (similar to that used for special prices and the "new" status of product) in magento? For example, I have a custom flag which tracks the status of a product. It would make it a lot easier if I could use a date range to set/unset that field.

(For example, when a product is marked as "coming soon" I add a tag to its image, which I manually unset once I make the product "new". Annoying to have to do it manually)

Comment: You can find the exact answer from here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178672/magento2-how-to-add-custom-product-attribute-of-type-date-range-ie-to-date-and

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create 2 attributes that hold 2 dates. Them being:

New From: (Date Value)
New To: (Date Value)

Then, you will have to go into the file where you want the attribute to display, check to see if the date is within the range of today's date.